Vector-based ldexp() function in GLSL
There's a function called ldexp() which adds a signed integer to float's exponent in GLSL, and I think it is much faster (add instruction) than division-by-POT (FDiv instruction), since I only need to divide my value by power-of-two.
The question: so far I only found a way to call it on a single float value, but is it possible to call it on vec3 value to involve SIMD?
Example of what I mean:
void main() {
   float input = 5.0f;
   float output = ldexp(input, -2); // no error, result is 2.5

   // what I want to do:
   vec3 vinput = vec3(5.0f); 
   vec3 voutput = ldexp(vinput, -2); // error! no ldexp() overload found which takes vec3.
}

Is it possible to call it on entire vector, instead of doing it for each vector component individually? If it is not possible, will it still be faster than a division instruction (again, consider that I only need division by power-of-two)?
